# How to make a gradient background for a LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I was wondering, what would be the best way to make a gradient background for a LinearLayout in java ( not xml ) ?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides xml you can also use [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) it has corresponding methods for all xml attributes

Answer (score 40):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#006499"
          android:endColor="#0093d7"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Set here startColor and endColor as your requirement and save this file in drawable folder

and in LinearLayout you can set this as `setBackground="@drawable/your gradient filename"`

Using java code you can do same thing using [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

Comment: Thanks! but will it be possible to change the gradient from java?

Comment: Is this the background of the Samsung Music Hub app or just a coincidence?