# MvvmCross How Binding BackgroudColor with gradiient color?

Tags: binding, mvvmcross

Now I binding BackgroudColor how:

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor Color, Converter=NativeColor;"
```

where Color is MvxColor.

Unfortunately, MvxColor not supported gradient.

Is there a way to create BackgroundColor with gradient?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported by standard mvvmcross - but you could easily implement this yourself by exposing some kind of GradientColor object which wrapped:

- the contained colours,
- their locations (stops)
- and the gradient angle

Once that was exposed from your viewModel, you could then implement binding to that.

For the various platforms:

- For Windows, you'd probably be able to work this out using some kind of GradientColorBrush.
- For iOS you might be able to use a `colorWithPatternImage` - [Make Background of UIView a Gradient Without Sub Classing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844710/make-background-of-uiview-a-gradient-without-sub-classing)
- For Android, you might be able to use a `GradientDrawable` - [How to make a gradient background for a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441857/how-to-make-a-gradient-background-for-a-linearlayout)

I think you might be able to do this binding at the UserControl, UIView and Android View level. The N+1 steps on custom controls and on custom bindings might come in useful for writing this - steps 18, 19 and 28 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com